# Does a person who newly became Indian Citizen need to pay taxes for the asset he transfers to India from his ex-citizenship country?

Tags: income-tax, india

Between 1992 and 2004 I was working in USA. I had also gained US Citizenship in 2003. In 2004 I returned to India and since then lived in India. I got (back) Indian citizenship in 2014. Now I want to transfer all my assets (which are savings while I was in USA and for which US income tax had been pained when the money was earned) in my US bank accounts to my RFC account in Indian banks. Do I need to pay tax in India for these assets?

Answer (score 1):

If the person has come back for good, any assets or foreign earnings can be transferred tax free back to India within 7 years.