# Moving back to India with my money; what will the tax liability be?

Tags: taxes, india

I am moving back to India and want to close my account here and transfer the money to an Indian account. What will the tax liability be? I don't hold an NRI account.

Comment: You're moving back to India from where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a person who newly became Indian Citizen need to pay taxes for the asset he transfers to India from his ex-citizenship country?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/35312/does-a-person-who-newly-became-indian-citizen-need-to-pay-taxes-for-the-asset-he)

Comment: Are you asking about the tax liability in the country you're leaving, or the tax liability in India?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are looking at moving your earnings when your tax status in India was NRI; then there are no taxes to be paid when you transfer the money back to India. You can move the funds back to India over a period of 7 years from the day you land.